# How to rotate an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector so as to be aligned with given axis?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations

Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary $n$-dimensional real vector. I would like to rotate it so as it be aligned to given axis.

Should I project it first to the given axis in order to calculate its angle wrt to this axis? How should I construct the $n$-dimensional rotation matrix then? I suspect that I might have a matrix with $n-2$ ones at its main diagonal?

I'm really stuck just at the very beginning of this. Can you please help?

Comment: rotation is an isometry, so why not just calculate the vector norm and multiply by unitary vector supporting the axis?

Comment: @zwim, you're absolutely right... Thank you, I didn't think it enough...